# DOSBox Exit to error: CPU_SetSegGeneral: Stack segment zero

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, clipper, dosbox

I am trying to run an old Clipper application. It runs fine on Win 7 32bit but when I try using the DOSBox 0.74 it crashes with the following error:

`Exit to error: CPU_SetSegGeneral: Stack segment zero`

Are there some settings I forget to set when running the DOSBox?

I need to be able to run this app in DOSBox as it appears to be only portable solution that would work on any Win 7, being it 32 or 64bit.

If no apparent solution is known for this problem maybe you can tell me what alternatives I have to run a Clipper 5.3 application on a Win 7 64-bit Home edition?

**EDIT:**
I tried it on Win 7 Home 64 bit with the very same result. What can I do?

Comment: Why is something like VmWare Player not an option?

Comment: @paxdiablo can you please elaborate on that how you would see it used?  I am just reading about the VmWare Player. But I suppose it will involve installation in it for example FreeDOS? Plus I am after a free solution since this would have to installed on many of clients machines.

Comment: Both VMWare Player and FreeDOS are free (in terms of cost - VMWare is closed source). I would just try to use it to see if the problem disappears in the first case, this may be a problem with DosBox itself. If it works, you can then examine the effort in your customers using it. If it doesn't work, forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanting to close this question I will write what was the only solution thanks to which I was able to run that aged application on Win7 64bit.

It was [VMLite XP Mode](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=143). 
I simply followed the steps described in their how to guide and it was up and running then I copied my application into the VMLite XP Mode, and it was running fine.

Finally I created, after some googling, a shortcut to my desktop and now I can easily start the application from my Win7 64bit desktop which then lunches the VMLite XP Mode which starts the application :) or something along this lines anyway, so far, it works great.

Answer (score 2):

I used clipper many years ago, clipper does cause problems because incorrect config.sys configuration, specially the setting "FILES" must be big enough (let´s say 200) for your application, but "original" dosbox does not provide a way to adjust this setting.

Try the patch from http://www.shdon.com/blog/2009/09/05/adjustable-files-setting-in-dosbox
This patch allows to configure FILES adding a new setting on dosbox options file

Steps:

- Backup dosbox.exe and replace it with the patched version
- Edit the dosbox options file and add FILES=200 to the [DOS] section

Try it and post the results since i don't have clipper 5.3 to test.

Comment: Thanks CesarC for taking your time (+1). Though I tried other methods of setting the FILES and the program still failed, I will give this one a try too and will let you know later tonight what happen.

Comment: Bad news it didn't help. It returns with the very same error.

Comment: Too bad, i recommend you to use "D-Fend Reloaded" because it have wizards for configurations, templates and makes it easier to play with dosbox options. Try with configurations like the PC where your applications used to run, play with "memory" options. Also it's posible that your programs run on a VMWare Player/FreeDOS configuration like someone already suggested.